# Function and Lambda expression in Julia when using minimize from python

Tags: python, lambda, import, julia, port

I have a code in Julia where I use the function minimize from python. Here I put a simplified example of it works the cose

```
using PyCall
@pyimport scipy.optimize as so

function fidelity1(x)
    f1 = x[1]*x[1]+3*x[2]*x[2]
    return f1
end

x0 = [1 1]
res = so.minimize(fidelity1,x0)
```

whose result is correctly

```
Dict{Any,Any} with 10 entries:
  "hess_inv" => [0.5 3.0102e-12; 3.0102e-12 0.166667]
  "fun"      => 2.22049e-16
  "nfev"     => 18
  "status"   => 0
  "message"  => "Optimization terminated successfully."
  "success"  => true
  "x"        => [-7.45039e-9, -7.45073e-9]
  "jac"      => [3.73556e-13, -9.08177e-13]
  "nit"      => 4
  "njev"     => 6
```

Now, it would be very useful to use a lambda expression, so I write the code in the following way

```
using PyCall
@pyimport scipy.optimize as so

fidelity2 = (x1,x2) ->  x1*x1+3*x2*x2

x0 = [1 1]
res = so.minimize(fidelity2,x0)
```

However, in this case I obtain

```
(in a Julia function called from Python)
JULIA: MethodError: no method matching (::var"#3#4")(::Array{Float64,1})
Closest candidates are:
  #3(::Any, !Matched::Any) at In[2]:4
Stacktrace:
 [1] #invokelatest#1 at ./essentials.jl:712 [inlined]
 [2] invokelatest(::Any, ::Any) at ./essentials.jl:711
 [3] _pyjlwrap_call(::Function, ::Ptr{PyCall.PyObject_struct}, ::Ptr{PyCall.PyObject_struct}) at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/callback.jl:28
 [4] pyjlwrap_call(::Ptr{PyCall.PyObject_struct}, ::Ptr{PyCall.PyObject_struct}, ::Ptr{PyCall.PyObject_struct}) at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/callback.jl:44
 [5] macro expansion at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/exception.jl:95 [inlined]
 [6] #109 at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/pyfncall.jl:43 [inlined]
 [7] disable_sigint at ./c.jl:446 [inlined]
 [8] __pycall! at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/pyfncall.jl:42 [inlined]
 [9] _pycall!(::PyObject, ::PyObject, ::Tuple{var"#3#4",Array{Int64,2}}, ::Int64, ::Ptr{Nothing}) at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/pyfncall.jl:29
 [10] _pycall!(::PyObject, ::PyObject, ::Tuple{var"#3#4",Array{Int64,2}}, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/pyfncall.jl:11
 [11] (::PyObject)(::Function, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/pyfncall.jl:86
 [12] (::PyObject)(::Function, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/pyfncall.jl:86
 [13] top-level scope at In[2]:7
 [14] eval at ./boot.jl:331 [inlined]
 [15] softscope_include_string(::Module, ::String, ::String) at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/SoftGlobalScope/u4UzH/src/SoftGlobalScope.jl:217
 [16] execute_request(::ZMQ.Socket, ::IJulia.Msg) at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/IJulia/IDNmS/src/execute_request.jl:67
 [17] #invokelatest#1 at ./essentials.jl:712 [inlined]
 [18] invokelatest at ./essentials.jl:711 [inlined]
 [19] eventloop(::ZMQ.Socket) at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/IJulia/IDNmS/src/eventloop.jl:8
 [20] (::IJulia.var"#15#18")() at ./task.jl:358

Stacktrace:
 [1] pyerr_check at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/exception.jl:62 [inlined]
 [2] pyerr_check at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/exception.jl:66 [inlined]
 [3] _handle_error(::String) at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/exception.jl:83
 [4] macro expansion at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/exception.jl:97 [inlined]
 [5] #109 at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/pyfncall.jl:43 [inlined]
 [6] disable_sigint at ./c.jl:446 [inlined]
 [7] __pycall! at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/pyfncall.jl:42 [inlined]
 [8] _pycall!(::PyObject, ::PyObject, ::Tuple{var"#3#4",Array{Int64,2}}, ::Int64, ::Ptr{Nothing}) at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/pyfncall.jl:29
 [9] _pycall!(::PyObject, ::PyObject, ::Tuple{var"#3#4",Array{Int64,2}}, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/pyfncall.jl:11
 [10] (::PyObject)(::Function, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/pyfncall.jl:86
 [11] (::PyObject)(::Function, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at /home/candeloro/.julia/packages/PyCall/tqyST/src/pyfncall.jl:86
 [12] top-level scope at In[2]:7
```

I can't figure out why the second code doesn't work

Comment: Does `res = so.minimize(fidelity2,x0...)` work? It's a little hard to test without a mwe

Comment: @OscarSmith no it doesn't, I obtain the same error

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but is there any particular reason why you are using scipy optimizer and not a corresponding Julia library?
Even if you get this working it will not be very performant.

Comment: `fidelity1(x)` takes 1 argument, and `fidelity2 = (x1,x2) -> ...` takes 2. That's what the lines above "Stacktrace" in the error are trying to tell you, you can also compare `methods(fidelity1)` to `methods(fidelity2)`. Perhaps you want `fidelity3 = ((x1,x2),) ->  x1*x1+3*x2*x2` (anon.) or `fidelity4((x1,x2)) = x1*x1+3*x2*x2` (named) which un-pack the one argument into two scalar variables.

Comment: @lungben I do searched some libraries which would optimize ~ minimize a scalar function depending on more than one parameters but I did not find any that could help. Do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) expects the objective function, in your case `fidelity2`, to take an array of size `(n,)` as its first argument that holds the values for `n` independent variables. While migrating to the second format where you use a lambda expression, observe that you also change the signature: `fidelity2` expects the independent variables in different function parameters rather than in an array, but that is *not* how `scipy.optimize.minimize` operates.

If all you want is to use lambda expressions, you may change `fidelity2` to be more like in your first example

```
using PyCall
@pyimport scipy.optimize as so

fidelity2 = x -> x[1]*x[1]+3*x[2]*x[2]

x0 = [1 1]
res = so.minimize(fidelity2, x0)
```

Note that you do not have to name your lambda expression. You may use it as an anonymous function inside your call to `minimize`. That means the following also works:

```
using PyCall
@pyimport scipy.optimize as so

x0 = [1 1]
res = so.minimize(x -> x[1]*x[1]+3*x[2]*x[2], x0)
```